# how to sum up columns from different dataframes into a single dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df1["Col1"] = [0,2,4,6,2] 
df1["Col2"] = [5,1,3,4,0]
df1["Col3"] = [8,0,5,1,7]
df1["Col4"] = [1,4,6,0,8]
#df1_new = df1.iloc[:, 1:3]

df2 = pd.DataFrame() 
df2["Col1"] = [8,2,4,6,2,3,5] 
df2["Col2"] = [3,7,3,4,0,6,8]
df2["Col3"] = [5,0,5,1,7,9,1]
df2["Col4"] = [0,4,6,0,8,6,0]
#df2_new = df1.iloc[:, 1:3]

dataframes = [df1, df2]

for df in dataframes:
    df_new=df.iloc[:, 1:3]
    print(df_new.sum(axis=0))
```

result from above looks like this:

```
Col2    13  
Col3    21  
dtype: int64
Col2    31  
Col3    28  
dtype: int64
```

But how can I sum up both dataframes and put it into a single one?

Result should look like this:

[image]

**Real example looks like this:**

```
xlsx_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
#print(csv_files)

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in xlsx_files: 
    # create df from each excel file
    dfs = pd.read_excel(f)
    # grab file name to user it in summarized df
    file_name =  f.split("\\")[-1]
    new_df = pd.concat([dfs]).iloc[:,13:28].sum()
```

Comment: Try `(df1 + df2).iloc[:, 1:3].sum()`?

Comment: Added another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either sum the dataframes separately and then add the results, or sum the concatenated dataframes:

```py
df1.iloc[:,1:3].sum() + df2.iloc[:,1:3].sum()

pd.concat([df1,df2]).iloc[:,1:3].sum()
```

In both cases the result is

```
Col2    44
Col3    49
dtype: int64
```

You can convert the result from a series to a DataFrame and transpose using

```
.to_frame().T
```

to get this output:

```
   Col2  Col3
0    44    49
```

For the code in your updated question, you probably want something like this:

```py
xlsx_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))
#print(csv_files)

# loop over the list of csv files
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in xlsx_files: 
    # create df from each excel file
    dfs = pd.read_excel(f)
    # grab file name to user it in summarized df
    file_name =  f.split("\\")[-1]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, dfs])

result = new_df.iloc[:,13:28].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. So in my real case I have to use a loop. And I am struggling to implement this logic inside the loop. I updated question

Comment: @Serdia please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Get the columnwise sums of both dataframes, take the middle two columns of each, and add them together. Then, transpose the result to turn the rows into columns:

```py
pd.DataFrame((df1.iloc[:, 1:3].sum() + df2.iloc[:, 1:3].sum())).T
```

This outputs:

```py
   Col2  Col3
0    44    49
```

Comment: Hey, sorry I modified slightly. Number of rows can be different in each dataframe. Sorry about that

Comment: Alright, see my edit.

Comment: @Nick -- OP edited the post between when I answered and when you commented.

Comment: Yeah, it is what it is. Happened to me yesterday as well, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```py
long, short = (df1, df2) if len(df1.index) > len(df2.index) else (df2, df1)
print((short[["Col2", "Col3"]].reindex(long.index, fill_value=0) + long[["Col2", "Col3"]]).sum().to_frame().T)
```

Or, if you need to use `iloc` for the columns, here is another way:

```py
long, short = (df1, df2) if len(df1.index) > len(df2.index) else (df2, df1)
print((short.iloc[:, 1:3].reindex(long.index, fill_value=0) + long.iloc[:, 1:3]).sum().to_frame().T)
```

Output (same for both):

```
   Col2  Col3
0    44    49
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way about it

combining the sum of the individual sum of the DFs, converting result to a DF and then choosing Col2 and Col3 after Transposing

```
(df1.sum() + df2.sum()).to_frame().T[['Col2','Col3']]
```

```
    Col2    Col3
0   44      49
```